# WIN32API returns only current machine name

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to collect all list of machines in local network, for that I am trying below code. But it always return me current machine name only. How Can I get all machines ip/name in local network?.

I have tried all SV_101_TYPES, among these some returns empty list and remaining returns only current machine name.

Could anyone guide me, what is wrong?

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList machines = NetApi32.GetServerList(NetApi32.SV_101_TYPES.SV_TYPE_ALL);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Class1.
    /// </summary>
    ///
    public class NetApi32
    {        
        // constants
        public const uint ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;
        public const uint ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;
        public enum SV_101_TYPES : uint
        {
            SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION = 0x00000001,
            SV_TYPE_SERVER = 0x00000002,
            SV_TYPE_SQLSERVER = 0x00000004,
            SV_TYPE_DOMAIN_CTRL = 0x00000008,
            SV_TYPE_DOMAIN_BAKCTRL = 0x00000010,
            SV_TYPE_TIME_SOURCE = 0x00000020,
            SV_TYPE_AFP = 0x00000040,
            SV_TYPE_NOVELL = 0x00000080,
            SV_TYPE_DOMAIN_MEMBER = 0x00000100,
            SV_TYPE_PRINTQ_SERVER = 0x00000200,
            SV_TYPE_DIALIN_SERVER = 0x00000400,
            SV_TYPE_XENIX_SERVER = 0x00000800,
            SV_TYPE_SERVER_UNIX = 0x00000800,
            SV_TYPE_NT = 0x00001000,
            SV_TYPE_WFW = 0x00002000,
            SV_TYPE_SERVER_MFPN = 0x00004000,
            SV_TYPE_SERVER_NT = 0x00008000,
            SV_TYPE_POTENTIAL_BROWSER = 0x00010000,
            SV_TYPE_BACKUP_BROWSER = 0x00020000,
            SV_TYPE_MASTER_BROWSER = 0x00040000,
            SV_TYPE_DOMAIN_MASTER = 0x00080000,
            SV_TYPE_SERVER_OSF = 0x00100000,
            SV_TYPE_SERVER_VMS = 0x00200000,
            SV_TYPE_WINDOWS = 0x00400000,
            SV_TYPE_DFS = 0x00800000,
            SV_TYPE_CLUSTER_NT = 0x01000000,
            SV_TYPE_TERMINALSERVER = 0x02000000,
            SV_TYPE_CLUSTER_VS_NT = 0x04000000,
            SV_TYPE_DCE = 0x10000000,
            SV_TYPE_ALTERNATE_XPORT = 0x20000000,
            SV_TYPE_LOCAL_LIST_ONLY = 0x40000000,
            SV_TYPE_DOMAIN_ENUM = 0x80000000,
            SV_TYPE_ALL = 0xFFFFFFFF
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SERVER_INFO_101
        {
            [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public UInt32 sv101_platform_id;
            [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string sv101_name;

            [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public UInt32 sv101_version_major;
            [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public UInt32 sv101_version_minor;
            [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public UInt32 sv101_type;
            [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string sv101_comment;
        };
        public enum PLATFORM_ID
        {
            PLATFORM_ID_DOS = 300,
            PLATFORM_ID_OS2 = 400,
            PLATFORM_ID_NT = 500,
            PLATFORM_ID_OSF = 600,
            PLATFORM_ID_VMS = 700
        }

        [DllImport("netapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "NetServerEnum")]
        public static extern int NetServerEnum([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string servername,
           int level,
           out IntPtr bufptr,
           int prefmaxlen,
           ref int entriesread,
           ref int totalentries,
           SV_101_TYPES servertype,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string domain,
           IntPtr resume_handle);

        [DllImport("netapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "NetApiBufferFree")]
        public static extern int
            NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr buffer);

        [DllImport("Netapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int NetMessageBufferSend(
            string servername,
            string msgname,
            string fromname,
            string buf,
            int buflen);

        public static int NetMessageSend(string serverName, string messageName, string fromName, string strMsgBuffer, int iMsgBufferLen)
        {
            return NetMessageBufferSend(serverName, messageName, fromName, strMsgBuffer, iMsgBufferLen * 2);
        }

        public static ArrayList GetServerList(NetApi32.SV_101_TYPES ServerType)
        {
            int entriesread = 0, totalentries = 0;
            ArrayList alServers = new ArrayList();

            do
            {
                // Buffer to store the available servers
                // Filled by the NetServerEnum function
                IntPtr buf = new IntPtr();

                SERVER_INFO_101 server;
                int ret = NetServerEnum(null, 101, out buf, -1, ref entriesread, ref totalentries, ServerType, null, IntPtr.Zero);

                // if the function returned any data, fill the tree view
                if (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS ||
                    ret == ERROR_MORE_DATA ||
                    entriesread > 0)
                {
                    IntPtr ptr = buf;

                    for (int i = 0; i < entriesread; i++)
                    {
                        // cast pointer to a SERVER_INFO_101 structure
                        server = (SERVER_INFO_101)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(SERVER_INFO_101));

                        //Cast the pointer to a ulong so this addition will work on 32-bit or 64-bit systems.
                        ptr = (IntPtr)((ulong)ptr + (ulong)Marshal.SizeOf(server));

                        // add the machine name and comment to the arrayList.
                        //You could return the entire structure here if desired
                        alServers.Add(server);
                    }
                }

                // free the buffer
                NetApiBufferFree(buf);

            }
            while
                (
                entriesread < totalentries &&
                entriesread != 0
                );

            return alServers;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe there are no other machines on your main domain? Perhaps you need to give an explicit domain name?

Comment: I am working in local network, Is something need to specify for local network?

Comment: Try using the name of your computer's Workgroup / Domain / Homegroup

Comment: What do you mean how to add workgroup? How to add your computer to a workgroup or domain?

Comment: How can I "Try using the name of your computer's Workgroup / Domain / Homegroup". If I have workgroup name say XYZ.

Comment: If you want to find out from Windows, what workgroup/domain your computer is on, go to desktop, right click Computer icon and select Properties from the pop-up menu. You'll get something like the second image here: http://www.dhakatips.com/tips/windows-7/configuring_file_and_printer_sharing_behavior_in_windows_7.html    You can use that name in your call to NetServerEnum instead of null. To get it programmatically, you can use NetGetJoinInformation Win32API function. It's only an idea of course.

Comment: o_weisman, thanks for help. Is it possible to collect all machines in network which have different workgroup. Suppose I have 100 machines of different workgroup and I don't know the name of any workgroup. and also I don't know the IP of any machine nor any fix subnet.

Comment: There is an example given here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/7d1a7de8-5498-42f9-8903-762596fd61c9/get-list-of-computer-from-all-domain?forum=wsk  but I don't know if it works properly. You basically call NetServerEnum with SVTYPEDOMAIN_ENUM first to get a list of domains.